# How do you add a header to an excel csv file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to add a header to a csv file dynamically. My current code looks like the following:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


rows = []

with open(r'Test_Timestamp.csv', 'r', newline='') as file:
    with open(r'Test_Timestamp_Result.csv', 'w', newline='') as file2:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            rows.append(row)
        file_write = csv.writer(file2)
        for val in rows:
            current_date_time = datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
            val.insert(0, current_date_time)
            file_write.writerow(val)
```

Currently how this works is it inserts a new timestamp at column A which is exactly what I want it to do, as I want everything to be pushed as I'll be working with csv files with various different number of columns.
What I'm having trouble with is, how am I able to add a column header? Currently a timestamp is created next to the header. I would want to create a new header named: `Execution_Date`

I have looked at pandas as a solution but from the documentation I've seen the examples given looks like its a set of column headers already pre-determined. I've tried inserting a column header with `df.insert(0, "Execution_Date", current_date_time)` but gives me an error when trying to accomplish this.

I know I'm fairly close to doing this but I'm running into errors. Is there a way to do this dynamically so it automatically does this with various different csv files and number of different columns in each csv file, etc.? The current output looks like:

[image: Example of results]

What I want the final result to look like is:

[image: Example of what final results should look like]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! I'm going to continue to see if I can solve this in the meantime, but I'm at a wall with how to proceed.

Comment: You want to write the header like `file_write.writerow(["Date","Title"])` prior to your for loop. Note you can get rid of rows if you write each row as you read it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the end result is something that excel can read like maybe a csv you can likely bypass pandas altogether:

**Edit:** adding support for existing titles

Given a simple csv like:

```
Title,Other
Geeks1,foo
Geeks2,bar
```

Then you might use:

```py
import contextlib
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    file_in = open('Test_Timestamp.csv', "r", encoding="utf-8")
    file_out = open('Test_Timestamp_Result.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="")

    reader = csv.reader(file_in, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(file_out)
    writer.writerow(["Execution_Date"] + next(reader))
    writer.writerows(
        [datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)] + row
        for row in reader
    )
```

to give you a file like:

```
Execution_Date,Title,Other
2022-02-11 00:00:00,Geeks1,foo
2022-02-11 00:00:00,Geeks2,bar
```

Comment: This does work for how its intended, however the csv files could have lets say 20 columns all with headers, then another csv file comes over with 15 columns with different naming conventions. So essentially, I just want to insert a new header `Execution_Date` then the rows below it with Timestamp. Then just move everything one column over. Just trying to find a dynamic way of doing this without needing to declare column headers, etc.

Comment: @Maykid I added support for existing column names.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to utilize `to_csv()`.

Example:

```
# importing python package
import pandas as pd
  
# read contents of csv file
file = pd.read_csv("gfg.csv")
print("\nOriginal file:")
print(file)
  
# adding header
headerList = ['id', 'name', 'profession']
  
# converting data frame to csv
file.to_csv("gfg2.csv", header=headerList, index=False)
  
# display modified csv file
file2 = pd.read_csv("gfg2.csv")
print('\nModified file:')enter code here
print(file2)
```

Comment: Interesting concept to consider. I'm trying to see if I dodge the `headerList` and leave it dynamic where the script just moves everything one column right, disregarding the headers and header names and just insert a new column with the timestamp in Column A only. Hopefully that makes sense.